# Open Source PHP Form/Survey Engine

Tags: php, forms, open-source

Does anybody know of any open source project that deals with creating forms or surveys?

The engine needs to function something similar to Survey Monkey (surveys; each containing survey pages; each containing a survey element - radio boxes/check boxes/text areas or other components) - except that we have requirements to brand it with custom look and feel and we have our own custom form interactions. I believe that some of these custom interactions might be worth contributing back to the OSS community as well, but we would rather plug it into an existing project that creating one from scratch.

It would be preferable if such a project used PHP and MySQL but I am fine with any other combination. Any inputs on this would be very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are. The following may suit you best:

- **[LimeSurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/)**
  LimeSurvey basically contains everything you need for doing nearly every survey with grace.
- **[ActiveCampaign](http://www.activecampaign.com/survey-software/)**
  Conduct surveys with ease by creating your survey using our proprietary WYSIWYG survey design tool, deploying your survey to your respondents, and fully analyzing the results.
- **[PHPESP](http://www.butterfat.net/wiki/Projects/phpESP/#PHPESP)**
  PHP scripts to let non-technical users create surveys, administer surveys, gather results, view statistics. All managed online after database initialization.

Comment: ActiveCampaign is not Open Source. phpESP is a dead project for quite some time.

Comment: I don't think ActiveCampaign offers surveys anymore anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend JForm (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jformphp/). It enables you to create easily customizable forms from a php settings array.

Answer (score 0):

I had built one custom survey as per my requirements  [over here](https://github.com/bhaveshbhide/simplesurvey). May be you can  customize it and make it as per your needs and you can host it on your server too. It uses PHP / MySQL. Its not a complete solution though.